# Can we use one Array.filter() method over several arrays?

Tags: javascript

I am currently filtering three arrays to return only the iterations that match the paratemer, something like:

```
filterMyArrays(parameter) {
 this.array1 = this.array1.filter(e => (e.item === parameter));
 this.array2 = this.array1.filter(e => (e.item === parameter));
 this.array3 = this.array1.filter(e => (e.item === parameter));
}
```

where all three arrays are based off the same original data return.

The code above (well, pseudocode, but you get the idea) is working as expected, but I was wondering if there is a method to create one single array.filter() instance that I can then invoke over several arrays, so my code becomes a bit cleaner and less repetitive. Something like, perhaps:

```
const myArrays = [array1, array2, array3]
myArrays.filter(e => (e.item === parameter));
```

or something like

```
let filterMySelection(desiredArray) = desiredArray.filter(e => (e.item === parameter));
array1 = filterMySelection(array1);
```

I have fiddled around with both attempts, but none of them worked.

Comment: You are assigning the same `this.array1.filter()` to `this.array1`, `this.array2` and `this.array3`. What are the arrays inside `[array1, array2, array3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
const myArrays = [array1, array2, array3];

const filteredArrays = myArrays.map(
  array => array.filter(e => e.item === parameter)
);

// OR

let filterMySelection = (desiredArray) => desiredArray.filter(
   e => e.item ===  parameter
);

const array1 = filterMySelection(array1);
```

Comment: This worked perfect, and out of simplicity, let filterMySelection = (desiredArray) => desiredArray.filter(
   e => e.item ===  parameter
); takes the cake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you can use map along with filter as follows:

```js
const combined_arrays = [array_1, array_2, array_3];

let result = combined_arrays.map(function(arr) {
    return [arr.filter(e => (e.item == parameter))];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixture of map and filter.

```
const myArrays = [array1, array2, array3];

let newArray = myArrays.map(k => k.filter(e => e.item === parameter));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [1, 3, 6, 8, 11];
var array2 = [4, 2, 5, 6, 15];
var array3 = [7, 4, 2, 6, 14];

var a = []

a.push(array)
a.push(array2)
a.push(array3)

//  OR
// a.push([1, 3, 6, 8, 11])
// a.push([4, 2, 5, 6, 15])
// a.push([7, 4, 2, 6, 14])


a.forEach((array, index) => a[index] = array.filter(function(number) { return number > 7; }))

var lucky = array.filter(function(number) {
    return number > 7;
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**Idea:**

- Save reference of all necessary array in another array.
- Loop on it using `.map` and return filtered list.
- Inside each iteration, filter current array and return result.
- Override necessary on `this` with filtered values

```js
var  arrs = [ this.array1, this.array2, this.array3 ];
var [ array1, array2, array3 ] = arrs.map((arr) => arr.filter((e) => e.item === parameter ));
Object.assign(this, { array1, array2, array3 });
```

---

You can also save filter function in a variable and use it in all filters:

```js
filterMyArrays(parameter) {
  const filterFn = (e) => (e.item === parameter)
  this.array1 = this.array1.filter(filterFn);
  this.array2 = this.array1.filter(filterFn);
  this.array3 = this.array1.filter(filterFn);
}
```